# Order By in Postgres

Tags: sql, postgresql, sql-order-by

I want to get the result set in the descending range order. Below is my Query

```
select quantity_range as quantity_range, count(*) as number_of_items,
sum(amount) as total_amount,
from (
  select *,case
    when quantity between 0 and 500 then '<=500'
    when quantity between 501 and 525 then '501-525'
    when quantity between 526 and 550 then '526-550'
    when quantity between 551 and 575 then '551-575'
    when quantity between 576 and 600 then '576-600'
    when quantity between 601 and 625 then '601-625'
    when quantity between 626 and 650 then '626-650'
    when quantity between 651 and 675 then '651-675'
    when quantity between 676 and 700 then '676-700'
    when quantity between 701 and 725 then '701-725'
    when quantity between 726 and 750 then '726-750'
    else '>750' end as quantity_range
  from Sales )
group by quantity_range order by quantity_range;
```

I want my Result set like:

```
<=500   100 100000.00
600-625 10  5000.00
>700    25  25000.00
```

How to get this ordering? If i give Order By clause then `>700` coming at 2nd position.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `RIGHT` to get last number from string:

```
select quantity_range as quantity_range, count(*) as number_of_items,
sum(amount) as total_amount
from (
  select *,case
    when quantity between 0 and 500 then '<=500'
    when quantity between 501 and 525 then '501-525'
    when quantity between 526 and 550 then '526-550'
    when quantity between 551 and 575 then '551-575'
    when quantity between 576 and 600 then '576-600'
    when quantity between 601 and 625 then '601-625'
    when quantity between 626 and 650 then '626-650'
    when quantity between 651 and 675 then '651-675'
    when quantity between 676 and 700 then '676-700'
    when quantity between 701 and 725 then '701-725'
    when quantity between 726 and 750 then '726-750'
    else '>750' end as quantity_range
  from Sales ) as sub
group by quantity_range 
order by RIGHT(quantity_range,3);
```

<kbd>**[`SqlFiddleDemo`](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/4cf7d/1/0)**</kbd>

Comment: It works great. I have one more query to display the amount range. There my amount will be `$1,000.00-$2,000.00` to `$9,000.00-$10,000.00` and finally `>$10,000.00` How to make this work?

Comment: @SatheshS Ask new question and you will get the answer + Prepare http://sqlfiddle.com so we can help you fast